# How can I pass the selected Kendo Menu Text to Controller

Tags: c#-4.0, kendo-ui

How can I pass the selected Kendo Menu Text to Controller???

```
menu.Add()
    .Text("Reports")
    .Items(item =>
     {
       item.Add().Text("Home").Action("Index","Sample");
       item.Add().Text("About Us").Action("Index", "Sample");
});
```

Since both the menu items call the same controller, I need to pass the Menu Items Text to the controller to identify which menu was selected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the route values:

```
item.Add().Text("Home").Action("Index","Sample", new { text = "home" });
item.Add().Text("About Us").Action("Index", "Sample", new { text = "about us" });
```